# JAVA : How to Open a small pop up when cursor passes on JButton?

Tags: java, jbutton, netbeans-7, onmouseover, java-6

I'm developing a Java GUI with NetBeans and I like that, whenever the cursor of the mouse is moved onto a `JButton`, a small pop-up containing information about the button shows up. I tried to look up on the net but I can't find anything. 
Any tips? 
Thank you.

Comment: have you use `jbutton.setToolTipText("some info")`?

Comment: Download and run https://java.net/projects/ojt-accessibility/downloads/download/Demos/SwingSet2.jar .  It demonstrates many of the Swing components available to you, including JToolTips, and it includes source code.